# smbnetfs - How to resolve Input/Output error while writing file to Windows Server share

Tags: linux, docker, samba, smb, fuse

I am using `smbnetfs` within a *Docker* container (running on Ubuntu 22.04) to write files from my application to a mounted Windows Server share. Reading files from the share is working properly, but writing files via `smbnetfs` gives me a headache. My Haskell application crashes with an `Input/output error` while writing files to the mounted share. Just 0KB files without any content are written. Apart from the application I've the same problem if I try to write files from the containers bash terminal or from Ubuntu 22.04 directly. So I assume that the problem is not related to *Haskell* and/or *Docker*. Therefore let's focus on creating files via bash within a *Docker* container in this SO question here.
Within the container I've tried the following different possibilities to write files, some with success and some non-success:

**This works:**

- Either `touch <mount-dir>/file.txt` => 0KB file is generated. Editing the file with *nano* works
  properly.
- Or `echo "demo content" > <mount-dir>/file.txt` works also. 
  (**Hint**: Consider the redirection operator)

Creating directories with `mkdir -p <mount-dir>/path/to/file/` is also working without any problems.

**These steps do not work:**

1. `touch <mount-dir>/file.txt` => 0KB file is generated properly.
2. `echo "demo-content" >> <mount-dir>/file.txt` => `Input/output error` 
   (**Hint**: Consider the redirection operator)

## Configuration

Following my configuration:

### **smbnetfs**

**smbnetfs.conf**

```
...
show_$_shares       "true"
...
include         "smbnetfs.auth"
...
include         "smbnetfs.host"
```

**smbnetfs.auth**

```
auth "<windows-server-fqdn>/<share>"        "<domain>/<user>"     "<password>"
```

**smbnetfs.host**

```
host <windows-server-fqdn> visible=true
```

### Docker

Here the *Docker* configuration.

**Docker run arguments**:

```bash
...
--device=/dev/fuse \
--cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
--security-opt apparmor:unconfined \
...
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM debian:bullseye-20220711-slim@sha256:f52f9aebdd310d504e0995601346735bb14da077c5d014e9f14017dadc915fe5
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Prerequisites
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      fuse=2.9.9-5 \
      locales=2.31-13+deb11u3 \
      locales-all=2.31-13+deb11u3 \
      libcurl4=7.74.0-1.3+deb11u1 \
      libnuma1=2.0.12-1+b1 \
      smbnetfs=0.6.3-1 \
      tzdata=2021a-1+deb11u4 \
      jq=1.6-2.1 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set the locale
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

# Copy runtime artifacts
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /home/vscode/.local/bin/Genesis-exe .
COPY entrypoint.sh .

## Prepare smbnetfs configuration files and create runtime user
ARG MOUNT_DIR=/home/moduleuser/mnt
ARG SMB_CONFIG_DIR=/home/moduleuser/.smb
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash moduleuser && mkdir ${SMB_CONFIG_DIR}

# Set file permission so, that smbnetfs.auth and smbnetfs.host can be created later
RUN chmod -R 700 ${SMB_CONFIG_DIR} && chown -R moduleuser ${SMB_CONFIG_DIR}

# Copy smbnetfs.conf and restrict file permissions
COPY smbnetfs.conf ${SMB_CONFIG_DIR}/smbnetfs.conf
RUN chmod 600 ${SMB_CONFIG_DIR}/smbnetfs.conf && chown moduleuser ${SMB_CONFIG_DIR}/smbnetfs.conf

# Create module user and create mount directory
USER moduleuser
RUN mkdir ${MOUNT_DIR}  
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Hint: The problem is not related to *Docker*, because I've the same problem within Ubuntu22.04.**

## **Updates:**

### **Update 1**:

If I start `smbnetfs` in debug mode and run the command `echo "demo-content" >> <mount-dir>/file.txt` the following log is written:

```
open flags: 0x8401 /<windows-server-fqdn>/share/sub-dir/file.txt
2022-07-25 07:36:32.393 srv(26)->smb_conn_srv_open: errno=6, No such device or address
2022-07-25 07:36:34.806 srv(27)->smb_conn_srv_open: errno=6, No such device or address
2022-07-25 07:36:37.229 srv(28)->smb_conn_srv_open: errno=6, No such device or address
   unique: 12, error: -5 (Input/output error), outsize: 16
```

### **Update 2**:

If I use a Linux based smb-server, then I can write the files properly with the command `echo "demo-content" >> <mount-dir>/file.txt`

#### **SMB-Server's Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.7@sha256:92251458088c638061cda8fd8b403b76d661a4dc6b7ee71b6affcf1872557b2b

RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
    samba-common-tools=4.7.6-r3 \
    samba-client=4.7.6-r3 \
    samba-server=4.7.6-r3

RUN mkdir -p /Shared && \
    chmod 777 /Shared

COPY ./conf/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf

EXPOSE 445/tcp

CMD ["smbd", "--foreground", "--log-stdout", "--no-process-group"]
```

#### **SMB-Server's smb.conf**

```
[global]
    map to guest = Bad User
    log file = /var/log/samba/%m
    log level = 2

[guest]
    public = yes
    path = /Shared/
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
```

### **Update 3:**

It also **works**:

- if I create the file locally in the container and then **move** it to the `<mount-dir>`.
- if I remove a file, that I created earlier (`rm <mount-dir>/file.txt`)
- if I rename a file, that I created earlier.(`mv <mount-dir>/file.txt <mount-dir>/fileMv.txt`)

### **Update 4:**

Found identical problem description [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/smbnetfs/bugs/35/).